# Two-bar plotting from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

I am not very experienced with python3 as I am still learning so I apology in advance if what I ask is pretty obvious.
So I have two files (.xlsx and .csv) with some data listed in different DataFrames.

```
exp=pd.read_excel('filepath/something.xlsx', keep_default_na=False)
sim=pd.read_csv('filepath/something.csv', keep_default_na=False)
```

Which look like these:

```
print(exp.dataframe_from_exp1)

0     2.2
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     2.7
4     3.5
5     1.3
6     2.2
7     3.0
8     2.1
9     1.7
10    2.5
Name: dataframe_from_exp1, dtype: float64

print(sim[[dataframe_from_sim1]])
        dataframe_from_sim1
0                   2.1
1                   1.3
2                   2.4
3                   2.9
4                   2.4
5                   2.8
6                   2.8
7                   3.6
8                   2.2
9                   2.7
10                  2.5
```

Then I arrange them in a dictionary by using their names:

```
comparison = {}
comparison['dataframe_from_sim1'] = 'dataframe_from_exp1' 
comparison['dataframe_from_sim2'] = 'dataframe_from_exp2'
```

And so on. Then, what I want is to plot each dataframe_from_sim with its corresponding dataframe_from_exp in a double-bar plot so I can compare the values from each variable in each of the 11 cases given and do it inside a `for` loop. Something like this:

```
N=11
x = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35
for key, value in comparison.items():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    bar1=ax.bar(x, key, width, color='r')
    bar2=ax.bar(x + width, value, width, color='b')
    plt.show()
```

But of course, this doesn't work. So if you could help me I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You would need to edit the question to include a sample for `exp` and `sim` and anything else to allow your problem to be recreated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to see these values side by side, the following will work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure()

exp = pd.read_excel('filepath/something.xlsx', keep_default_na=False)
sim = pd.read_csv('filepath/something.csv', keep_default_na=False)    

exp.plot.bar(color='red', ax=fig.gca(), position=0, width=0.3)
sim.plot.bar(color='blue', ax=fig.gca(), position=1, width=0.3)

plt.show()
```

Giving you:

[image: side by side bar plots]

This could be extended to work on multiple pairs of files as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import pandas as pd
import glob

for xlsx_filename in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(xlsx_filename)
    csv_filename = '{}.csv'.format(name)

    if os.path.exists(csv_filename):
        exp = pd.read_csv(csv_filename, keep_default_na=False)
        sim = pd.read_excel(xlsx_filename, keep_default_na=False)    

        fig = plt.figure(name)
        exp.plot.bar(color='red', ax=fig.gca(), position=0, width=0.3)
        sim.plot.bar(color='blue', ax=fig.gca(), position=1, width=0.3)
        plt.title(name)

plt.show()
```

This searches for pairs of `.xlsx` and `.csv` filenames. Only files with a matching pair are processed.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. But how can I do it for in a `for` loop so I automatically get the plots of each DataFrame in the files (that is for dataframe_from_exp2 and dataframe_from_sim2, dataframe_from_exp3 and dataframe_from_sim3, etc.) without writing the same code again and again for each pair of DataFrames? That's why I thought I could use a dictionary...

Comment: Are you trying to read lots of `.xlsx` and `.csv` files, all with similar data? Are they pairs of data? e.g. one `.xlsx` with one `.csv`?

Comment: Yes, they are pairs of data. In each `.xlsx` and `.csv` I have 10 variables and its N values (in this particular case, N=11), each variable in each `.xlsx` has her sister in the `.csv` file. What I am trying to do is print the 10 graphs that would result from each pair of files by just using a `for` loop with the keys and values of the dictionary (which are the variables of the `.csv` and the `.xlsx` respectively)

Comment: So file `abc.xlsx` would have a matching `abc.csv` and so on?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: File pairs could be done using `glob.glob()` to find all the `.xlsx` files, and a check to find a matching `.csv` file. I have updated the script to show this.